# MultipeerConnectivity between iOS and Windows

Tags: c#, ios, windows, multipeer-connectivity

I have started implementing MultipeerConnectivity in my iOS and OSX apps so that they can exchange data.

There are plans to develop a Windows version of the app. Is there any way I can implement MultipeerConnectivity in C#?

I am aware that I can advertise using Bonjour, but will there be methods such as sendData and didReceiveData on Bonjour SDK for Windows?

I have indeed looked for this, but I couldn't find much information regarding Bonjour on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, Bonjour service support is available on Windows, but I believe the other parts of MPC are limited to iOS and OS X at the moment.